# How to pass container link to child container?

Tags: docker

I run postgres container:

```
docker run --name db -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

Then I run some container A with link to postgres container:

```
docker run --name A --link=db:db [other params]
```

Now I am inside container A and want to run container B from here. And B needs `db` link as well. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple: Just pass `--link=db:db` to the child container as well. Example:

```
$ docker run --rm -d --name db postgres:alpine
$ docker run --rm -it --name contA --link=db:db -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker:stable
  / # ping db
  PING db (172.17.0.2): 56 data bytes
  64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.357 ms
  [...] # works
  / # docker run --rm -it --name contB --link=db:db alpine:latest
    / # ping db
    PING db (172.17.0.2): 56 data bytes
    64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.388 ms
    [...] # works as well
```

(`$` is the Bash of the local machine, `/ #` is the Shell of `contA`/`contB`. I've tried to indent things to hopefully make the level of the rabbit hole clear.)

Answer (score 0):

You can start a container from another container, but I think it's not what you want. You can start container `B` with the same command as `A`, just change the name. You can communicatie with containers by using the container name as host. To access `db` from `A` you run `postgres -h db`. When you run `ping db` you can see the actual IP adres of the `db` container.

Comment: I definitely can start a container from another container. For example `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker run postgres echo 43`. And it's exactly what I want. The thing is container `A` does bunch of stuff and sometime runs containers.

Comment: Fair point, I've updated my answer. There're not a lot of context in your question, but can't you use a queue system? Or add jobs to the database and make a container that checks for new jobs in the Postgres database.